# A helper function for mysqli that dynamically binds params in prepared statement?

Tags: php, function, mysqli, foreach, bindparam

I'm trying to create a function for my project. I would like it to handle all the check functions. What I mean with that is before you start inserting a row in your database you check if a row exists with that email address.

To use this function dynamically it needs to be flexible. So I did put my variables in an array, but `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` can't handle arrays. As a solution, I tried making a `foreach` loop.

The query:

```
$sql = "SELECT users_id, users_email FROM users WHERE users_id = ? AND users_email = ?;";
```

Calling the function:

```
check_database($sql, array($id, $mail), array("s", "s"), $location);
```

My original function:

```
function check_database($sql, $variables, $types, $location)
{
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db/db.inc.php';
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: " . $location . "?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, $variables);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I added a `foreach` to the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` like this:

```
foreach ($types as $index => $type) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $type, $variables[$index]);
}
```

This gives me an error and I don't know how to solve it :(

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: Can yo8u show us the query?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's in the question! I edited it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on a very right track! Such a function should be an everyday companion for the every PHP programmer using mysqli, but strangely, only few ever have an idea of creating one.

I've had an exactly the same idea once and implemented a [mysqli helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) of my own:

```
function prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params, $types = "")
{
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

Main differences from your approach

- the connection is made only **once**. Your code connects every time it executes a query and this is absolutely NOT what it should do
- it can be used for any query, not only SELECT. You can check the versatility of the function in the examples section down in the article
- types made optional as most of time you don't care for the type
- no bizarre $location variable. Honestly, whatever HTTP stuff should never be a part of a database operation! If you're curious how to properly deal with errors, here is my other article [Error reporting in PHP](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)

With your example query it could be used like this

```
$check = prepared_query($sql, [$id, $mail])->get_result()->fetch_row();
```

or, if you want a distinct function, you can make it as well

```
function check_database($mysqli, $sql, $params, $types = "")
{
    return prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params, $types)->get_result()->fetch_row();
}
```

and now it can be called as

```
$check = check_database($sql, [$id, $mail]);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!! It looks very nice! I only have one question! What goes in the `$mysqli` parameter?

Comment: The mysqli connection that you must create strictly once at the beginning and then use it all the way during the script execution